# Copy or clone a specific Element from XML to the same XML

Tags: c#, xml, copy, nodes, clone

i want to copy or clone a specific node or Element from XML. I tried many codes, but no one worked. I am program with C#.

Here is my XML, I  hope my problem is clear!

[This is my XML before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFEEJ.png)
[I want this XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzkOZ.png)

I can´t do this manually, because I need more than 30 Tools more.

Answer (score 0):

it really depends on what you are using to parse the xml.

I will give you info for the two most used classes for parsing an xml in .NET.

1. `XmlDocument`: then you can use [.CloneNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.clonenode(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. `XDocument`: then you can do something like this:

   `XElement` toCopy = ...;

   `XElement` copy = `XElement.Parse(toCopy.ToString());`

If you are not familiar with xml processing in .NET, there is enough information in msdn for [XDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/is-is/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/xdocument-class-overview) and [XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx).